# Why does Spark fail with "Detected cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using **Spark 2.1.0**.

When I execute the following code I'm getting an error from Spark. Why? How to fix it?

```
val i1 = Seq(("a", "string"), ("another", "string"), ("last", "one")).toDF("a", "b")
val i2 = Seq(("one", "string"), ("two", "strings")).toDF("a", "b")
val i1Idx = i1.withColumn("sourceId", lit(1))
val i2Idx = i2.withColumn("sourceId", lit(2))
val input = i1Idx.union(i2Idx)
val weights = Seq((1, 0.6), (2, 0.4)).toDF("sourceId", "weight")
weights.join(input, "sourceId").show
```

Error:

```
scala> weights.join(input, "sourceId").show
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Detected cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans
Project [_1#34 AS sourceId#39, _2#35 AS weight#40]
+- Filter (((1 <=> _1#34) || (2 <=> _1#34)) && (_1#34 = 1))
   +- LocalRelation [_1#34, _2#35]
and
Union
:- Project [_1#0 AS a#5, _2#1 AS b#6]
:  +- LocalRelation [_1#0, _2#1]
+- Project [_1#10 AS a#15, _2#11 AS b#16]
   +- LocalRelation [_1#10, _2#11]
Join condition is missing or trivial.
Use the CROSS JOIN syntax to allow cartesian products between these relations.;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.CheckCartesianProducts$$anonfun$apply$19.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1011)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.CheckCartesianProducts$$anonfun$apply$19.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1008)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:287)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:293)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:293)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:331)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:188)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:329)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:293)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:293)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:293)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:331)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:188)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:329)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:293)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:277)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.CheckCartesianProducts.apply(Optimizer.scala:1008)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.CheckCartesianProducts.apply(Optimizer.scala:993)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:85)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:57)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:66)
  at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foldLeft(WrappedArray.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:75)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2791)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2112)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2327)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:248)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:636)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:595)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:604)
  ... 48 elided
```

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I just downloaded Spark 2.1.0 from the official website and it presents the same issue (in the local shell). Spark 2.1.1 works fine instead.

Comment: Confirmed. I could reproduce it with 2.1.0 too. Yes, 2.1.1 works fine. Scala does not matter as I use the official version that's built with Scala 2.11.8 (and that's why I removed it as a "noise").

Answer (score 49):

You can triggers inner join after turning on the flag

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")
```

You also could also use the cross join.

```
weights.crossJoin(input)
```

or set the Alias as

```
weights.join(input, input("sourceId")===weights("sourceId"), "cross")
```

You can find more about the [issue SPARK-6459](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6459) which is said to be fixed in 2.1.1

**As you have already used 2.1.1 the issue should have been fixed.**

Comment: neither of the alternatives work for me... same exact exception. The issue that you pointed out is supposed to be already fixed in the version of Spark that I'm using.

Comment: I have encountered the same exception in same version of and the alias worked for me.

Comment: which join are you trying to do?do  a specific join right, left rightouter, leftouter etc.

Comment: I need to do an "inner" join and it does not work. No issue if I specify "left_outer"

Comment: I don't need a cross join. I need an inner join.

Comment: "spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true his enables the inner join.

Comment: My question is if i set spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true"), then Does it execute inner join as per code

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr** Upgrade to Spark 2.1.1. It's an issue in Spark that was fixed.

(I really wished I could also show you the exact change that fixed that in 2.1.1)

Comment: Is there a workaround if we are not able to upgrade to Spark 2.1.1?

Comment: do you know how issues is fixed? I have spark 2.2 and I am still getting this issue where spark misinterprets regular join as a cartesian product.

Comment: I'm also still hitting this issue on Spark 2.2, on a join which doesn't actually have a cartesian product (or a join which should be trivially inferred).  Updating isn't a great solution unless there is a documented fix in place.

Answer (score 4):

For me:

```
Dataset<Row> ds1 = sparkSession.read().load("/tmp/data");
Dataset<Row> ds2 = ds1;
ds1.join(ds2, ds1.col("name").equalTo(ds2.col("name"))) // got "Detected cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans"

Dataset<Row> ds1 = sparkSession.read().load("/tmp/data");
Dataset<Row> ds2 = sparkSession.read().load("/tmp/data");
ds1.join(ds2, ds1.col("name").equalTo(ds2.col("name"))) // running properly without errors
```

I'm using Spark 2.1.0.

Comment: What is the change?

Answer (score 1):

Got this error in SPARK version:
2.3.0.cloudera3

Solved by aliasing the dataframes.

e.g. re-assigning the failing dataframe to another dataframe and aliasing the name to that other dataframe.

`val dataFrame = inDataFrame.alias("dataFrame")`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this on top of the command
SET spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled = TRUE;

If your query is complex, may be re structure the query to get better result

Comment: how do we re structure the query in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Just enable joins at the beginning of your code like this:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.leftJoin.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.leftOuterJoin.enabled", "true")
```

add the join name which you are using. It worked for me.