# Pyspark join expression errors when using dataframe column's property method

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes that I'd like to join. The schema for the DFs look like the following:

```
itemsDF.printSchema()

root
 |-- asin: string (nullable = true)
 |-- brand: string (nullable = true)
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- url: string (nullable = true)
 |-- image: string (nullable = true)
 |-- rating: float (nullable = true)
 |-- reviewUrl: string (nullable = true)
 |-- totalReviews: integer (nullable = true)

reviewsDF.printSchema()

root
 |-- asin: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- rating: float (nullable = true)
 |-- date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- verified: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- helpfulVotes: float (nullable = true)
```

And I would like to join the two data frames by the column `asin`. This expression appears to work without error:

```
reviewsDF.join(itemsDF, reviewsDF['asin'] == itemsDF['asin']).show()
```

However, the following expression gives an error:

```
reviewsDF.join(itemsDF, reviewsDF.asin == itemsDF.asin).show()
```

```
AnalysisException: 'Detected implicit cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans\nProject [asin#347, name#348, cast(rating#349 as float) AS rating#459, cast(cast(unix_timestamp(date#350, MMMM dd, yyyy, Some(America/Los_Angeles)) as timestamp) as date) AS date#458, cast(verified#351 as boolean) AS verified#460, title#352, cast(helpfulVotes#354 as float) AS helpfulVotes#461]\n+- Relation[asin#347,name#348,rating#349,date#350,verified#351,title#352,body#353,helpfulVotes#354] csv\nand\nProject [asin#846, brand#847, title#848, url#849, image#850, cast(rating#851 as float) AS rating#864, reviewUrl#852, cast(totalReviews#853 as int) AS totalReviews#865]\n+- Filter (isnotnull(asin#846) && (asin#846 = asin#846))\n   +- Relation[asin#846,brand#847,title#848,url#849,image#850,rating#851,reviewUrl#852,totalReviews#853,prices#854] csv\nJoin condition is missing or trivial.\nEither: use the CROSS JOIN syntax to allow cartesian products between these\nrelations, or: enable implicit cartesian products by setting the configuration\nvariable spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true;'
```

Why does the second expression fail?

Comment: Is your reviewsDF and itemsDF derived from the same dataframe ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44762353/why-does-spark-fail-with-detected-cartesian-product-for-inner-join-between-logi

Comment: @Jaydeep no they are not from the same dataframe.